# SSO Best Practices: What are solutions for unreachable IDP?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, cas

Here's [something similar to this question on general SSO best-practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291874/best-practices-for-building-a-sso-system). What is the best approach for dealing with a disabled or for-whatever-reason-unreachable central identity provider. If your website allows users to login with their centrally-stored credentials, and the central service is not working or unreachable do you:

- Allow users to re-enter their credentials on the local site, so that they can use the native login facility of the web application (or content management system or whatever)
- Allow users to request another secondary set of credentials that they can use on the web application itself (i.e., a separate password they can use when the IDP is down) [NOTE: obviously this defeats the 'single credentials' goal just tossing out all ideas].
- Allow the users to login using any of several various maintainers of the same credentials (by giving them multiple links to multiple providers, and then trying each one of them until one of them actually connects and works)

For probably apparent reasons, none of these *solutions* above seem attractive, so feel free to put these on the "worst practices" list while you answer with the best alternative approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd think the best way would be to have *decentralized* SSO, as is implemented in Open ID. If each account can have many providers, then if one provider goes down, you can fail over to another.

On the other hand, if centralized SSO is required. The only thing that I can think of would be to have the central authority generate a cryptographic certificate for each user. If the service has a fresh copy of the certificate revocation list and a cached copy of the central authority's public key, it can validate certificates even if the central authority is unavailable. Unfortunately, this method would probably suffer from usability issues as users would need to both keep a copy of their certificate handy and know what you're talking about when you ask for it.

Comment: That second idea sounds good best-practice wise, but yeah, user-friendly is definitely not an attribute of that approach. Then again security and authentication rarely is user-friendly, I guess that's the point. Thanks for the idea.